# Ionic 3 - Register new element is formBuilder

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ionic3, formbuilder

I have added a custom slider element in the [formBuilder](https://formbuilder.online/). The code is as below:

```
var fields = [{
    label: 'Rating',
    attrs: {
      type: 'slider'
    },
    icon: ''
  }];

  var templates = {
    slider: function(fieldData) {
      return {
        field: '<input type="range" min="0" max="10">'
      }
    }
  };

  $(container).formBuilder({
    templates,
    fields
  });
```

The JSON data it generates is as below:

```
[
  {
    "type": "slider",
    "required": false,
    "label": "Rating",
    "name": "slider-1643115075076-0",
    "access": false
  }
]
```

But when I pass this data to `formRender` method on my app I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Invalid control type. (Type: slider, Subtype: undefined). Please ensure you have registered it, and imported it correctly.
```

How do I register this new element such that it appears on my app?

Comment: Same error showing that my process